# Applying calc() on a rasterstack with certain pixels with all NA values

Tags: raster, r, time-series, bfast

I have a raststack of 768 NDVI files with 4.1 million pixels each. Now I am performing a pixel based time series method (BFAST) using the following functions:

#### Function to convert daily ts into monlthy ts

```
aggregate.daily.to.monthly <- function(daily.ts) {
  s.month <- round(aggregate(as.zoo(daily.ts), as.yearmon, median), 0)   
  s.month <- as.ts(s.month)
  return(s.month)
}
```

#### xbfast function to convert rasterstack into a ts object and apply BFAST

```
xbfast <- function(data) {
  s <- bfastts(as.vector(data), dates, type = c("irregular"))
  s.d.linear <- round(na.omit(s, method = "ie", interp = "linear"), 0) 
  s.m.linear <- aggregate.daily.to.monthly(s.d.linear)
  result <- bfast(s.m.linear, h = 0.13, season="dummy", max.iter=2)
  return(cbind(result$Magnitude, result$Time))
 }
```

#### Performing calculation on rasterstack

Now I use `calc()` from raster package to apply xbfast on rasterstack `ndvi` which as dates function attached to it:

```
 fbfast <- calc(ndvi, fun = function(x){
      t(apply(x, 1, xbfast))
 })
```

> Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) :
>   cannot use this function

The above error appears because **certain pixels have all NA values** and xbfast function does not work on such pixels. The above code is tested on few other areas and it produces results. Apparently, the error is given for those areas which have certain pixels with all NA values.

In order to skip calculations on those pixels which have all NAs I used `na.rm` argument but it doesn't run.

`fbfast <- calc(ndvi, fun = function(x){ 
  t(apply(x, 1, xbfast)) }, na.rm = TRUE)`

> Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : cannot
>   use this function. Perhaps add '...' or 'na.rm' to the function
>   arguments?

Modified code using `is.na`

```
fbfast <- calc(ndvi, fun = function(x){
  if (all(is.na(x))) {
    NA
  } else {
    t(apply(x, 1, xbfast))
  }
})
```

> Error in apply(x, 1, xbfast) : dim(X) must have a positive length

I modified the code:

```
fbfast <- calc(ndvi, fun = function(x) {
  if (all(!is.na(x))){
    t(apply(x, 1, xbfast))
    } else {
      rep(NA, 2)
  }})
```

It runs and produces a rasterbrick of 2 layers but with only NAs! What could be wrong here?

I intend to produce three rasters (magnitude of breakpoints, timing of breakpoints and number of breakpoints). First 2 are part of `xbfast` but I couldn't find a way to produce number of breakpoints.

Comment: I have nothing but problems with the function check in `calc` and `overlay` and have just started writing my own function versions for these types of applications. That said, have you used the `na.rm` argument in `calc`? Try `na.rm=TRUE` in the `calc` function to handle NA values before they hit your function.

Comment: One thing the make sure is that the return of an NA check returns the same length vector as if the function has values. That is to say, if your function is returning 5 values from `bfast`, then you must return 5 NA values (not 1 as in your code) in the case of `if(is.na(x))`. I would just add `rep(NA,5)` as the returned value.

Comment: I find it useful to test my functions outside of another function. Have you tried your function on a simulated time series vector? Is the function, in fact, returning a vector or are you transposing a data.frame or matrix object? According to the `bfast` function a list object is returned. The `x[["output"]]` object is a list containing list of each time series component. So, what are you outputting and how is it formatted? You could also just coerce the stack to an SpatialPixelsDataFrame object and then apply the function across the rows of the @data slot. This is a common workaround.

Comment: Where does `xbfast` come from? Its not in the `bfast` package.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code from your comments to it so that the question makes a complete example. Then delete the comments.

Comment: I edited the question now.

Comment: As are result of using `cbind`, your xbfast function is returning a matrix, not a vector as expected. Use `c(result$Magnitude, result$Time)`. I am also having a difficult time running a stable instance of your code on NDVI data. I had to modify your call to `bfastts` to make it work.

Comment: I tried with `c(result$Magnitude, result$Time)` and it gives the same error! How did you modify `bfastts`?